# sending the dropdown option selected value from index.php page to search.php in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

```
                This is my controller 

                    function search($collg_id = '', $id = '') {
                      $courserecord = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered');
                      $data['course_offrd_name'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
                      if (empty($data['course_offrd_name'])) {
                        $data['course_offrd_name'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
                      } else {
                        $courserecord = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered');
                        $data['course_offrd_name'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
                      }
                    }


                This is my model.php

                    function get_data_wheree($table) {
                      $this->db->select('course_offrd_name, collg_id');
                      $this->db->group_by('course_offrd_name');
                      return $this->db->get('tbl_course_offered')->result();
                    }

                This is my source view page ie index.php dropdown page

                    <form class="form-horizontal well bar" action="<?php echo base_url();?>search" method="post" role="form">
                      <div class = "col-md-2">
                        <div class = "form-group">
                          <div class = "col-md-12">
                            <select class = "course" name = "course_offrd-name[]" id = "course_offrd_name" class = "form-control">
                              <option value = "">Select</option>
                              <?php
                                foreach ($coursedata as $val) {
                                ?>              
                                  <option value="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name; ?>">
                                  <?php echo $val->course_offrd_name; ?>
                                  </option> 
                                <?php
                               }
                              ?>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                    </form>
                    <script>
                      $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("select.course").change(function () {
                          var selectedCourse = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
                          alert("You have selected the course - " + selectedCourse);
                        });
                      });
                    </script>



                <--this is my  second view page ie search.php where myselected option should display--> 

                    <form class="form-horizontal well" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>search" method="post" role="form">
                      <span>
                        <?php foreach ($coursedata as $val) {
                        ?>
                        <p>
                        <input class="with-gap filter_course CheckCourse" name="course_offrd_name[]" multiple type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name; ?>"  value="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name ?>" 
                        <?php
                          if (!empty($courserecord))
                          if (count($courserecord) == 1)
                          if ($courserecord[0]['course_offrd_name'] == $val->course_offrd_name) {
                            echo $courserecord[0]['course_offrd_name'];
                            echo "checked";
                          } else {
                        }
                        ?> />
                        <label for="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name ?>"></label>
                        </p>
                        <?php } ?> 
                      </span>
                     </form>
                This is my ajax code 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        $(".course").on('change', function() 
                        {

                        var level = $(this).val();
                        if(level)
                        {


                            $.ajax ({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: base_url+"home/search",
                                data: { course_name: 'course_name' },
                                success : function(htmlresponse) 
                                {

                                    $('#opt_lesson_list').html(htmlresponse);
                                    console.log(htmlresponse);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>

                This is my home controller index function  page
                public function index()
                    {
                        if($this->session->userdata('user_login'))
                        {
                                if($this->input->post())
                                {

                                $data   = array();
                                $data['state_name']=$this->input->post('state');
                                $data['country_name']=$this->input->post('country');
                                $data['course_name']=$this->input->post('course_name');
                                $data['sub_cat_id']=$this->input->post('subcategory_name');
                                $data['catgy_id']=$this->input->post('category_name');
                                $data['collg_name']=$this->input->post('collg_name');

                                }
                $coursedata= $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered');
                                    $data['coursedata']=$coursedata;


            This is search function in home controller 
            public function search($collg_id='',$id='')
                {
                    if($this->session->userdata('user_login'))
                    {

                                if($this->input->post())
                                {

                                $data = array();
                                $data['email']=$this->input->post('email');
                                $data['password']=$this->input->post('password');
                                $data['isactive']=1;
                                $data['collg_id']=$this->input->post('collg_id');
                                $where=array();


                                    if($this->input->post('course_name')!='')
                                    {
                                        $where['tbl_college.course_name']=$this->input->post('course_name');
                                        $data['course_name']=$this->input->post('course_name');

                                    }
                                    $where['isactive']=1;

                                    $select='`tbl_college`.`collg_id`,`collg_name`,`logo_img`,`header_img`,`phone_no`,`state`,`country`,`city`,`tbl_college`.`isactive`,`pdf_name`,`tbl_college.category_name`,`tbl_college.subcategory_name`,`tbl_college.course_name`';
                                        /
                                    $record=$this->get_uniquedata($this->front->selected_data($select,'tbl_college',$where),'collg_id');

                                    $data['record']= json_decode(json_encode($record), True);


                                   if(empty($data['record'])){

                                        $this->session->set_flashdata("success","No Records found");
                                         redirect(base_url());
                                    }
                                    else{
                                                     $data['subcategoryrecord']= json_decode(json_encode($subcategorydata), True);              }
                                                     $courserecord = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered');


                                                      $data['course_offrd_name'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);

                                                     if(empty($data['course_offrd_name']))
                                                      {

                                                     $data['course_offrd_name'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
                          }
                          else 
                           {
                $courserecord = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered');
                                         $data['course_offrd_name'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);


                           }
            }
            }
                                else{

                                    $record = $this->front->get_data_where('tbl_college',array('isactive'=>'1'));
                                        //$data['record']= json_decode(json_encode($record), True);
                                //  echo "<pre>";print_r($data['record']);die;
                                    $data['record']=$record;
                                    }

                        $data['record']=$record;
            $coursedata = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered');
                        $data['coursedata']=$coursedata;
            $this->load->view('home/search',$data);
            }






                I want to send the dropdown option selected values from one view page to another view page in CodeIgniter using ajax or jQuery. 

                The option value which is selected should be sent from index.php to search.php. It should just display the value name in search.php 
                If required will provide more code. How can be it done?

                Now I have code in search() function. I have made changes in code. Please see this search function.
                how to do it using CodeIgniter and ajax, how we can send the dropdown option already selected and send from one view to another view page using CodeIgniter and Ajax

                if need more code will be provided. 
            I have added the ajax code and controller index function 
            check the above code ....if required more code will post 
            Thanks in advance
            I have added the ajax code and controller index function  code 
            I have added the ajax code and controller index function code 
            I have added the ajax code and controller index function code 
    I have added the search() of home controller .
    I have added the search() of home controller .
I have added the search() of home controller .
I have added the search() of home controller .
        I have added the search() of home controller .
        If required more code will provide
        I have added the search() of home controller .
        I have added the search() of home controller .
        I have added the search() of home controller .
```

I have added the search() of home controller .
I have added the search() of home controller .
if required more code will provide 
Thank in advance M.hemant for taking interest in my code.
if u need more code or table structure will provide
Thank in advance M.hemant for taking interest in my code.
if u need more code or table structure will provide

Comment: Please always edit your formatting code properly, I edited your question, if something miss there then add details in your question

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya Thanks, I am expecting this indentation from Diwakar. Anyway, Diwakar where is your ajax code which sends your selected option values to the controller and passes that to new ajax? can you show us your controller and Ajax code, Are you facing any error in ajax?

Comment: @M.Hemant CHECK I HAVE UPDATED WITH AJAX AND CONTROLLER CODE

Comment: Did you get $_POST in search()? if yes then please share with us one more thing if you are passing data to search then why you using two params in that function and where you are using $_Post param in you where condition?

Comment: @M.Hemant i have added the search()  function check the edited code

Answer (score 0):

I believe (* there is a lot of code here so forgive me if this isn't it) but I believe the problem is because you are doing:

`data: { course_name: 'course_name' },`

When you should be doing:

`data: { course_name: selectedCourse },`

You are sending text/string of "course_name" rather than the actual value from your select drop down.